# How to run letter_recog.cpp example of OpenCV 3 successfullly?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to run the **letter_recog.cpp** example with the 64-bit OpenCV 3. But during the process, it report the debug: **Expression: vector subscript out of range**.

When I step into the OpenCV source code to find out what is wrong, and it stops at the line of the **memcpy(&subsets[split.subsetOfs], &w->wsubsets[wsplit.subsetOfs], ssize*sizeof(int));**.

It is one line of the function **int DTreesImpl::addTree(const vector& sidx )**.

In the letter_recog.cpp example, I choose **the build_rtrees_classifier**. The train data after the **prepare_train_data(data, responses, ntrain_samples)** is

And the debug error happens in the function of **model = StatModel::train(tdata, RTrees::Params(10,10,0,false,15,Mat(),true,4,TC(100,0.01f)));**

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Or how can I run the `**letter_recog.cpp** example successfully? Because I do not have enough reputation points, I can not post image.

Thanks a lot!`

Comment: try other classifiers(like SVM, knearest), but maybe make an [issue here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues) . it would be interesting to see, if the boosting classifier crashes too (it's also using DTrees under the hood)

Comment: yes, the boosting crashes too. made an [issue](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4085)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I originally thought there was some default in my OpenCV settings.

Comment: i have to thank you, i guess. was running into this now & then before, but never had a proof. ;)